# How to login at register using Spring Security and Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

It's got to be a simple question, but I'm struggling here. How can I login as user at registration using Spring Security and Spring Boot?

It's a fairly simple use case where I'd like to save a user a trip to a login page after a successful registration. There are plenty of examples using form auth for log in, and plenty of registration examples that are all pretty trivial. But what about register + login in one go?

I'm not sure what to try here.

Comment: You have to build the `Authentication` yourself and then store it in the `SecurityContext` like that: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html#store-authentication-manually